# jQuery/Javascript get notified when a function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, observer-pattern, notify

```
var f = function() {
    // Do something useful here
};
```

Is there a way to 'observe' this function, and get notified when it is executed? Something similar to *bind* in jQuery, but I want to *bind* functions and not dom events?

I **don't want** something like this:

```
var f = function() {
    // Do something useful here
    notifyObserver();
};
```

but **I want** something like this:

```
f.bind(function() {
    alert('F was executed.');
});
```

Comment: So what you really want is a callback function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could replace f with a function that calls notifyObserver:

```
f = (function(oldF){
      return function(){
        notifyObserver(); 
        oldF(); 
      }; 
    })(f);
```

That way you don't need to modify (the old) f itself. This doesn't include your `bind` functionality, of course. I'd probably create some kind of manager class for this where you can register event handlers

```
manager.bind('f', function(){...});
```

And creating the wrapper function would look more like

```
f = (function(oldF){
      return function(){
        manager.notify('f');
        oldF(); 
      }; 
    })(f);
```

You can generalize the creation of the wrapper:

```
function wrap(methodToWrap, eventName){
    return function(){
        manager.notify(eventName);
        return methodToWrap.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

(This works with any number of arguments and return values!)

And then do something like:

```
f = wrap(f, "f");
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/NBefc/2/ (updated, no with return values)

Comment: Interesting solution :) How would you use something like this?

Comment: awesome solution, Andre.  I would only add that this assumes f does not take any arguments.  But for [a quick demo of this](http://jsfiddle.net/NBefc/), I threw together a program that replaces `alert` with this kind of function.  It also takes the one argument but I'm not sure how you would handle multiple dynamically.  The demo just adds a console.count to the normal alert function.

Comment: @JosephMarikle: I've updated your example with a demo that works with arguments and return values: http://jsfiddle.net/NBefc/2/

Comment: @AndreLoker bravo! nicely done.  I'll have to keep that in my js arsenal :)

Comment: Great solution. Meanwhile I was reading this post: http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-observer-class/. It can be useful for others too.

Comment: Instead of providing an explicit event name, you could try `methodToCall.name`, but I'm not 100% this works well all the time.

Comment: @TamasPap This should work great together with my suggestion. You could enhance it by allowing multiple events. Or you use multiple Observers, one for each event. Instead of passing in an eventName to wrap you'd pass in the observer to call `fire` on.