# How to detect when a JavaScript function runs?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use something like an `eventlistener` to detect when a JavaScript function runs. I want to detect it outside the actual function, and not just make this happen inside the function.

Comment: You can "detect" it, if you wrap the function you want to run.

Comment: No, there is not. If for debugging purposes - use breakpoints

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Is there a way to at least view it when debugging in with inspect?

Comment: I want to allow a user to run different functions on the page and whatever function is run I want to be able to detect it.

Comment: [jQuery/Javascript get notified when a function is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544614)

Comment: You can use Rx Subject.

Comment: *"I want to allow a user to run different functions on the page"* Where are those functions coming from? How is the user selecting them?

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(func())`'ing the function then use CurrentTime to display time.

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack a function, like this:

```js
const oldLog = console.log
let run = 0

console.log = function () { 
  ++run; // or anything you need
  oldLog.apply(this, arguments) 
}
```